# Deduce average order of $\phi(n)/n$ from probability that two integers are coprime

Tags: pr.probability, riemann-zeta-function

I've seen proofs of the fact that the probability of two random integers being coprime is $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$ (all of them leading to a use of the Riemann Zeta function and the Basel problem). In several cases it was mentioned that one can easily deduce from that the fact that the average order of $\phi(n)/n$ is also equal to $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$. To me this is not clear, maybe I am missing something obvious. Is this deduction possible and if it is, is there a easy way to see it?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to say that the probability that two random integers are coprime is $6/\pi^2$ since there's no uniform probability distribution on the integers. (You can say if you choose two integers uniformly in the range $\{1,\ldots,N\}$, then the probability that they are coprime approaches $6/\pi^2$ as $N\to\infty$).

Comment: Yes of course you are right, that is what I meant by 'two random integers being coprime'. The phrasing is a bit unfortunate perhaps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the rigorous statement that "two random integers have a $6/\pi^2$ probability of being coprime" is
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{m=1}^N
\mathbf 1_{m\text{ and }n\text{ are coprime}}\to \frac 6{\pi^2}.
$$

This is the same as
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac 2{N^2}\sum_{n=1}^N
\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\mathbf 1_{m\text{ and }n\text{ are coprime}}\to \frac 6{\pi^2}.
$$

Or

$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac 2{N^2}\sum_{n=1}^N \phi(n)\to \frac 6{\pi^2}.
$$
Using summation by parts, we have:
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\phi(n)}n=
\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac 1N \left(
\frac {S_N}N + \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{S_n}{n(n+1)}\right),
$$
where $S_n=\phi(1)+\ldots+\phi(n)$. The previous equality shows $S_N/N^2\to 3/\pi^2$, so that the limit on the right of the displayed equation converges to $6/\pi^2$ as required.

Answer (score 0):

As $\phi(n)$ counts the number of integers co-prime to it from $1$ to $n-1$, we would expect there to be $\dfrac{6}{\pi^2}$ of them.

Comment: Presumably you mean $\frac{6n}{\pi^2}$ of them.  This is a decent heuristic argument, but it still does need to be made rigorous.